# Jasper Reports - Exporting excel file with multi-sheet reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I was trying to make a jasper report that when exported as an excel file, it will generate different reports for each sheet
the idea would be:
1. sheet 1 = Invoice report
2. sheet 2 = Sales details report
4. sheet 3 = Summary report
Many thanks and best regards,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

set the net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet property to true

```
<propertyname="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
```